# implement async in a foreach .net 4.5 mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach, .net-4.5

in working to develop a new post method. I found that I am running into extremely long wait times on a bottleneck `foreach` statement. I am saving between 5 and 8k(depending on the items being sent) to the database. The method succeeds, but usually takes upwards of a full 60 seconds. I have been looking into how to actually execute an async method, but I am not sure this will actually solve the problem.

This is the full method

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ConfirmSend(int? SystemGeneralAnnouncementId) { 
        var systemGeneralAnnouncement = (SystemGeneralAnnouncementId == null) ? null : _uow.SystemGeneralAnnouncementRepository.GetById(SystemGeneralAnnouncementId.Value);
        List<Status> status = new List<Status>();

            if (systemGeneralAnnouncement.Statuses.Length > 0)
            {
                status.AddRange(systemGeneralAnnouncement.Statuses.Split(',').Select(item => (Status) Enum.Parse(typeof (Status), item)));
            }

            var allEmailAddresses = new List<PointOfContact>();
            var EmailAddresses = new List<PointOfContact>();


            var result = new List<PointOfContact>();
            foreach (var item in status)
            {
                result = _uow.PointOfContactRepository.GetAllByStatus(item).ToList();
                allEmailAddresses.AddRange(result);
            }


            if (systemGeneralAnnouncement.SendToRecipients.Contains("(1) All Three Contact Types"))
            {
                mailAddresses = allEmailAddresses;
            }
            else
            {
                if (systemGeneralAnnouncement.SendToRecipients.Contains("(2) All Contacts "))
                {
                    EmailAddresses.AddRange(allEmailAddresses.Where(r => r.PointOfContactType == PointOfContactTypes.Primary).ToList());
                }
                if (systemGeneralAnnouncement.SendToRecipients.Contains("(3) All Compliance contacts"))
                {
                    pocEmailAddresses.AddRange(allEmailAddresses.Where(r => r.PointOfContactType == PointOfContactTypes.Secondary).ToList());
                }
                if (systemGeneralAnnouncement.SendToRecipients.Contains("(4) All Authorities"))
                {
                    pocEmailAddresses.AddRange(allEmailAddresses.Where(r => r.PointOfContactType == PointOfContactTypes.SigningAuthority).ToList());
                }
                if (systemGeneralAnnouncement.SendToRecipients.Contains("(5) All Rate Contacts"))
                {
                    EmailAddresses.AddRange(allEmailAddresses.Where(r => r.PointOfContactType == PointOfContactTypes.TuitionRates).ToList());
                }
                if (systemGeneralAnnouncement.SendToRecipients.Contains("(6) Specified Email Address"))
                {
                    var pocs = new List<PointOfContact>();

                    string[] emails = systemGeneralAnnouncement.EmailAddresses.Split(',');

                    foreach (string email in emails)
                    {                      
                        var addContact = new InstitutionPointOfContact { Email = email };

                        User user = _uow.UserRepository.GetByEmail(email);

                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            addContact.FirstName = "Not Created Account Yet";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            addContact.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                            addContact.LastName = user.LastName;
                        }

                        List<PointOfContact> idAssociatedToUser =
                            _uow.PointOfContactRepository
                                .GetAllByEmail(email)
                                .ToList();


                        if (idAssociatedToUser.Count == 0)
                        {
                            addContact.IDNumber = "N/A";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string[] opeidArray = opeidAssociatedToUser
                                .Select(x => x.OPEIDNumber)
                                .ToArray();

                            addContact.OPEIDNumber = string.Join(",", opeidArray);
                        }
                        Contacts.Add(addContact);
                    }                  
                    EmailAddresses.AddRange(Contacts);
                }
            }
```

The Specific `Foreach`

```
    if (EmailAddresses.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (PointOfContact emailAddress in EmailAddresses.Where(x => x.Email != "").ToList())
                    {
                        string firstName = emailAddress.FirstName == null ? "" : emailAddress.FirstName.Trim();
                        string lastName = emailAddress.LastName == null ? "" : emailAddress.LastName.Trim();

                        string userName = firstName + " " + lastName;

                        string emailBody = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(systemGeneralAnnouncement.EmailBody);

                        SaveToDatabase(emailAddress.Email, emailBody, systemGeneralAnnouncement.Subject, UserIdentityHelper.GetUserEmailAddress + " (" + UserIdentityHelper.GetUserId + ")", systemGeneralAnnouncement.SystemGeneralAnnouncementId, userName, emailAddress.OPEIDNumber);
                        LogInstitutionEmail(systemGeneralAnnouncement.Subject, emailBody, emailAddress.Email, emailAddress.OPEIDNumber, systemGeneralAnnouncement.EmailAttachmentLocation);
                    }
                }
                return View("GeneralAnnouncementGeneratedConfirmation");
            }
```

And the Database methods:

```
        private void LogInstitutionEmail(string subject, string emailBody, string email, string opeidNumber, string emailAttachment)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MasterContext"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into InstitutionEmails (Since, Subject, Email, EmailAddress, OpeidNumber, FirstReadDateTime, Attachment) VALUES(@Since, @Subject, @Email, @EmailAddress, @idNumber, NULL, @Attachment)", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Since", Value = DateTime.Now });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Subject", Value = subject });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Email", Value = emailBody });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmailAddress", Value = email });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@idNumber", Value = idNumber });

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailAttachment))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Attachment", Value = emailAttachment });
                    }

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        private void SaveToDatabase(string emailRecipient, string emailBody, string subject, string userWhoSentIt, int systemGeneralAnnouncementId, string userName, string opeidNumber)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MasterContext"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into EmailQueue (EmailRecipients, EmailBody, EmailSubject, UserWhoSentIt, QueueDate, SystemGeneralAnnouncementId, UserName, idNumber) VALUES(@EmailRecipients, @EmailBody, @EmailSubject, @UserWhoSentIt, @QueueDate, @SystemGeneralAnnouncementId, @UserName, @idNumber)", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() {ParameterName = "@EmailRecipients", Value = emailRecipient });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmailBody", Value = emailBody });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmailSubject", Value = subject });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@UserWhoSentIt", Value = userWhoSentIt });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@QueueDate", Value = DateTime.Now });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@SystemGeneralAnnouncementId", Value = systemGeneralAnnouncementId });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@UserName", Value = userName });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@idNumber", Value = idNumber });


                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

My Question is two fold. First, is async a viable option with this type of Code (Using Sql server 2012) as I noticed in my research that if you have a database level bottleneck, async could potentially cause dead lock. Second, If Async/await is viable, what would be the best way to actually implement it?

**Update**: The post method is only retrieving the Id of the SystemGeneralAnnouncement, and the confirmation to start the method. All of the actual execution is being handled inside the method itself.

**Update 2:** For clarifications Sake, these items are being passed to a task scheduler that fires at a later date, and takes all the stored items in the queue, then delivers them in the background. This is why I am using the SQL call.

Comment: If you do implement async/await it will need to be done from the bottom to the top.  That is the main async methods you call will be in ADO.Net and as you add `await` you'll make the method `async` and that would bubble up to your controller.  You'd then want to make an ajax call to the controller to make the entire round trip asynchronous.

Comment: @jpears, well if you're trying to optimize your query, you should probably not hit your database in a loop, because you will get alot of additional latency on each call.  On top of that It might just be better to store you email as text on the file system instead and just store a path to your text file

Comment: @johnny5 Thank you for the response. If I were going to move the SavetoDatabase, and LogInstitutionEmail methods outside of the loop, would It still be best to put them into an async method?

Comment: Instead of making SQL call in, you can create an SP and do a bulk insert. This will reduce the DB calls significantly.

Comment: @jpears,  Ideally you should convert your project to use EntityFramework, which will provide these async methods for you.  You can do async either way, but you will see the most performance gain just from, 1. Not loading your users in the foreach, and 2. Not calling your save changes in the foreach these are the things slowing you down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if you have a database level bottleneck, async could potentially cause dead lock

Not at all.

However, `async` won't help you run *faster* - that's a common misconception.

What you want to do is a batch update.

Comment: Stephen Cleary. I read some of your blog posts on this subject, thank you for the clarification on the misconception. As Johnny5 pointed out, it appears I need to move the call outside the foreach. I will look into the use of Batch Update.

Comment: I cannot currently upvote. i will do so as soon as possible.